# C# Windows Phone 8.1 runtime: how to make a task survive beyond app lifecycle?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, async-await, windows-8.1

I have this kind of Task

```
    private async Task SaveToFile(StorageFile file)
    {
        // prepare data
        await ...
        Debug.Writeline("completed");
    }
```

If the user press "back" button this task won't be completed. I need a way to make it go on until all it's done, even if the calling app is not running any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have To use **"background Task"** for this. Its pretty simple,
create a new project for background tasks and add it to your solution, because your background task is a not a simple class its a separate WINRT project. To do this, right-click on your solution node in the Solution Explorer and select Add->New Project. Then select the Windows Run-time Component (Universal Windows) project type, name the project, and click OK. I named here "BackgroundStuff". You can create more than one background task for single application. there is no any limit.
**Consider simple example to generate toast even App is not running:**

```html
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string myTaskName = "MyBackgroundClass";
    // check if task is already registered
    foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
        if (cur.Value.Name == myTaskName)
        {
            await (new MessageDialog("Task already registered")).ShowAsync();
            return;
        }
    // Windows Phone app must call this to use trigger types (see MSDN)
    await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
    // register a new task
    BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder { Name = "MyBackgroundClass", TaskEntryPoint ="MybackgroundStuff.MyBackgroundClass" };
    taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, true));
    BackgroundTaskRegistration myFirstTask = taskBuilder.Register();
```

**If you want to learn more , refer my blog:**
http://windowsapplife.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not force a Task to keep running, if the parent process is terminated.

That said, the issue you've described is not really an issue unless your file takes longer than 10 seconds to save (which is an eternity, in computer lingo).

Windows Phone apps continue to run in the background for up to 10 seconds, after the user 'backs' out of it, or manually quits.  This should be enough time for any application to finish its 'cleanup' operations.

See: [App Lifecycle Windows Runtime Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh464925.aspx#app_suspend)

See also: [App activation and deactivation for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: it doesn't take 10 seconds, but 2 o 3, this is due to encoding and transformations. I call it this way: await SaveToFile(file). if I wait untile debug line appear all it's done correctly, but a user could not wait for it

Comment: your link does not concern my app, I use windows 8.1 with windows runtime not silverlight or 8

Comment: The same rules apply.  Your Task has 10 full seconds to complete, AFTER a user closes the app.  It should not be an issue.

Comment: Downvote...why?  This is the correct answer to the question, as-asked.

Comment: You are right at your place, but Background Task is simple solution to problem. Sorry to cross but please chk once

Comment: Um, no, creating a completely new project to add support for background tasks which are used solely to save a file is NOT a simple solution; its a huge amount of overkill, for what turns out not to be a problem at all.  Microsoft designed the life-cycle of apps to be very generous.

Comment: it's not so generous because the user could be faster and close the app before the file is correctly saved, even if saving takes less than a second

Comment: Read the answer again; if the user closes the app, the app will raise the 'deactivated' event, and continue to run in the background for a FULL TEN SECONDS.  This is guaranteed by the operating system.  The app has all the time in the world to finish saving data, once the 'Deactivated' event is raised.